# How to browse /usr in an Open File dialog?

Tags: macos, finder, filesystem

I came to the necessity of browsing and picking up a file from `/usr` while using some programming tools, but I cannot do so because `/usr` seems to be hidden from Open File dialog.

Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Inside the Open File dialog, press : <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd> . This will let you enter a path.

type `/usr` and press <kbd>return</kbd>